# how to make Assassins Creed Valhalla render on GPU?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, gaming

I have a AMD Ryzen 9 7950x CPU, which happens to have integrated graphics, and a dedicated Nvidia RTX3090 GPU, and the game Assassins Creed Valhalla choose the Ryzen to render graphics.. How do i make it render on the GPU instead?

Fwiw in Nvidia Control Panel, i've put both ACValhalla.exe and ACValhalla_Plus.exe to use 3090, but it still somehow manage to pick AMD.

i -THINK- I can disable Ryzen graphics entirely in BIOS, forcing it to use the 3090, but I'm hoping not to do that, as it would probably increase power consumption/power bill to have the 3090 do everyday non-gaming tasks..

just in case it's relevant:

- Valhalla version 1.7.0
- Windows 10 version 22H2
- Nvidia driver 546.01
- AMD Adrenaline version 22.40.70-230620a-393743C-Channel
- AMD Windows Driver Version - 31.0.14070.0

all the drivers should be reasonably up to date..
[image]

Comment: Check *Settings > System > Display > Graphics Settings* if "Hardware Accelerated GPU" is enabled. Check also the video settings of the game itself.

Answer (score 1):

Plug the display into the discrete GPU.

Unlike laptops, desktop PCs do not have the functionality to dynamically switch between an iGPU (integrated) and dGPU (discreet), which actually routes the graphics output of the dGPU through the iGPU.

You may disable the iGPU in BIOS to simplify display negotiation during POST. Typically idle GPU power (for non-3D applications) is quite low - the GPU firmware and driver negotiate down to a much lower performance and power state automatically when GPU power isn't required. Although this level is likely higher than the iGPU's idle power, it's not likely to be a significant expense. Some users report that Ryzen 9 7950X's GPU's idle power is around 8W, and some reviewers determine that GeForce RTX 3090's idle power is around 20W. If you left the system on and idle every second for a full year, you would pay approximately $17.14 dollars extra for the dGPU to be idle (based on those numbers and the average cost of power in the US). However, consider that right now your dGPU is powered and idle.